# Inside .each() function jQuery

Tags: jquery, each

I've got this

```
<div id=results">
    <article>
        <span class="sel">Text Here</span>
    </article>
    <article>
        <span class="sel">Text Here</span>
    </article>
    <article>
        <span class="sel">Text Here</span>
    </article>
</div>
```

Got a jQuery to know wich "span" I've clicked:

```
$("#results").on('click', 'article .sel', function() {
    var index = $(this).index("#results article .sel");
});
```

If I would like to change that "span" class, how I could do it?

I thought about doing an .each() function for each "article", but I wouldn't know how to enter the "span" inside the .each() function.

May there is an easier way that I don't know.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clicked element is referenced by `this` so

```
$("#results").on('click', 'article .sel', function() {
    var index = $(this).index("#results article .sel");
    //to change the class
    $(this).addClass('newclass');//or do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks, worked fine, so I really don't need the index, thought I would need it to change the class. But thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `removeClass()` and `addClass()` (or even `toggleClass()`) to change the class of an element.

```
$(".sel").on("click", function()
{
    $(this).removeClass("sel").addClass("yournewclass");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, just another question when I added a new class.

The new class have a font-weight in css, if I change the text, it doesn't appear bold. Can make it somehow that the new text I introduce gets the new style of the class I added?

Comment: The `span` will get the styles of the CSS which are defined in the "yournewclass" class. If it doesn't get styled, it might be overwritten by other CSS.